# Breaking out of a for loop from a catch block

Tags: c#

Is finally executed in this case? I wrote this code and couldn't decide if finally is really executed in this case or not. I would really like some explanations no matter what the answer is.

```
foreach(string s in allStrings)
{
    try
    {
        //Error happens here
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //Handle exception
        break;
    }
    finally
    {
        //Clean up code
    }
}
```

Comment: "Have you tried it?"

Comment: I ran an experiment, i timed how long it would take to create this question, and i timed how long it would take to put that in a console app and click "Run". The console won. Okay i didn't really run an experiment but you get the point. :)

Comment: [*cough*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150186/breaking-out-of-a-for-loop-from-a-catch-block/4150190#4150190)

Comment: Apologies, I was writing a SharePoint WebPart late in the night... Yes I tried it after sometime. Apologies again for not selecting an answer quickly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've written 90% of the code that you'd need to answer this question for yourself.

Keep writing.

Answer (score 8):

Yes.  Finally blocks are *always* executed when control leaves a corresponding try or catch block.  (Unless something super-special happens, like a runtime crash or the thread was aborted.)

Answer (score 2):

Effectively, finally blocks are ALWAYS called.  That's the reason they're named that way...

Answer (score 2):

Based on Matt's answer. It is a total overkill indeed.

I suggest doing something like this, and making sure that the test passes.
MSTest is not the best library for testing, but it is the "Standard" :)

```
[TestClass()]
public class FinalClauseTester 
{ 
    private TestContext testContextInstance;
    public TestContext TestContext 
    { 
        get
        {
            return testContextInstance;
        } 
        set
        {
            testContextInstance = value; 
        } 
    } 

    [TestMethod] 
    [DeploymentItem(@"Something right goes here.")] 
    [DataSource("Something else goes here", "row", somethingOtherSetupCrap)] 
    public void TestFinalClause() 
    {

        string[] allStrings = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
        int yesCount = 0;
        foreach(string s in allStrings)
        {
            try
            {
                //Error happens here
                throw new Exception();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //Handle exception
                if (yesCount == 3)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                //Clean up code
                yesCount++;
            }
        }

        // And, at the end of this loop ...
        Debug.Assert(yesCount = 3); // Or something like this.
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing this while on payroll on for a tight school deadline is a bad idea in this particular case; getting used to writing tests (although this case is an overkill) can pay off at some distant future.

Comment: Your foreach statement does not have a closing `}`.  Also, since `yesCount` starts as 0, the end result would be `yesCount == 1` since the first time through the loop you threw an exception which called `break` which terminated the loop (after running the finally block).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. Finally blocks always are executed. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Comment: This question was about C#, not Java.

Comment: Careful, the question is about C#, not Java (However, your statement is still true).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it tries the try, then catch catches the exception, and then finally is what is finally called for both normal execution and caught exceptions. I think there's a witticism hiding somewhere!